# Resilience4j new instance of Retry or retrieve from RetryRegistry?

Tags: resilience4j

When protecting a method using Retry, should I create a new instance each time or reuse the same instance from the RetryRegistry?

Which one should I use?

A)

```
for(int i: mylist){
Retry retry = Retry.ofDefaults("backendName");
Mono.fromCallable(backendService::doSomething).transformDeferred(RetryOperator.of(retry))
}
```

or

B)

```
RetryRegistry retryRegistry = RetryRegistry.ofDefaults();
for(int i: mylist){
Retry retry = registry.retry("backendName");
Mono.fromCallable(backendService::doSomething).transformDeferred(RetryOperator.of(retry))
}
```

Shouldn't a Retry always be a new instance to keep track of the states and the number of attempt or is the registry behind the scene returns a new instance when we invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use b).
You must not create a new Retry instace per call. The Retry instance internally creates a new Retry context per subscription.
You should even do the lookup only once in your constructor.